# If no user input (in C)

Tags: c

I am thinking, I want to write a code where if no user input then do something else. i.e when I ask for the input and the user doesn't input anything he presses enter then the code does something else..

I have tried several ways in C but can't seem to work, it keeps waiting for the user input even after pressing enter.. I will appreciate a little help

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
int input[2];
int i=0;

while(i<2){
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    if (input[0] == NULL){
        break;
    }
    i++;

}
```

On the null part I have tried several other stuffs like '\0' '\n' nothing works... What am I forgetting or misunderstanding?

Comment: `"I have tried several ways in C"` ... show it

Comment: Include the code you have so far in the question, that way we can give better advice.

Comment: Step 1: show one of the things that *didn't* work. This question will be closed fairly quickly, otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried gets()?

Comment: @NTN, no, `gets` is dangerous in `C89` , deprecated in `C99` and doesn't exist in `C11`

Comment: @NTN i am trying to input an integer to an array, so gets even though it works the way i want when a user presses enter, still I wouldn't use it the other way i.e. when i want an integer

Comment: Now that you included some code I voted to reopen this question. This code will give you segmentation faults and other very undesirable behavior because you are going to overrun the array bounds if you get enough input because `i` will keep getting incremented and eventually go past the last element of the array.

Comment: And look up `fgets`.

Comment: @user3564573 `gets` is the way to go; it doesn't provide the solution as-is. You have to do `sscanf` on the output of `gets`; you can then use the return value of `sscanf` to decide whether the user provided input. BTW you should replace `gets` by `fgets` or `getline` because `gets` is deprecated.

Comment: Read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Test the result of `scanf`. Your question is unclear, and the answer might be operating system specific. On POSIX or Linux consider [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: @user3564573 You seem to have a little confusion about how an `int` array works. You're testing the 0th element for `NULL`. But since `NULL` is just 0 you're actually testing if the user inputted a 0 at the first prompt. Also keep in mind it's not a `char` array. `int`s are not `/0` terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by other people, input a line of text (`getline` or `fgets`) and parse it (`sscanf`). This might be a better practice in the general case too (when the user must enter data), because it always reads the whole line of input, while `scanf` reads only a part of the line, leaving the rest in the input buffer.

```
int input[2];
char* line = NULL;
size_t size = 0;

...

getline(&line, &size, stdin);
if (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &input[0], &input[1]) == 2)
{
    // do what you need with the input
}
else
{
    // user didn't supply data - do something else
}
```

Note that `getline` allocates some memory dynamically; if you use it, you should free the memory correctly.

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t size = 0;

...

getline(&line, &size, stdin);

...

free(line);
```

Using dynamic memory allocation is not trivial; you might want to ask a separate question if you're not sure you did it right. The code examples above are a bit lazy (don't check for EOF and NULL) and can be improved.